# How to use HANDLE from windows-rs and rust

Tags: windows-rs

I'm trying to call `LockFileEx` on a `std::fs:File` and struggle since type `HANDLE` has multiple implementations:

```
windows::Win32::Foundation::HANDLE
std::os::windows::io::BorrowedHandle
std::os::windows::raw::HANDLE
```

My current attempt is as follows:

```rs
fn unsafe lock(file: &mut File) -> BOOL {
    let mut overlapped = std::mem::zeroed();
    LockFileEx(
        file.as_handle(),
        LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK,
        0,
        !0,
        !0
        &mut overlapped)
}
```

This fails with

```
the trait `From<BorrowedHandler<'_>>` is not implemented for `HANDLE`
```

I'm kind of puzzled because of the different `HANDLE` types and was wondering how to make them fit together.

Comment: The `HANDLE` types provided by the Rust Standard Library and the `HANDLE` type provided by the `windows` crate are unrelated. The best you can do is use [`as_raw_handle()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-AsRawHandle) instead, and `as`-cast your way through until you can instantiate a [`HANDLE`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.HANDLE.html). Or start from [`CreateFileW`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Storage/FileSystem/fn.CreateFileW.html) and get features that are missing from POSIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HANDLE` in Windows is a moniker that identifies a kernel object. Its native type is `void*` with its value carrying no inherent meaning. Its sole purpose is to refer that object in communication with the OS, and any library (such as Rust's Standard Library) that needs to interact with the OS will provide a way to represent `HANDLE` values.

At the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), where rubber meets the road, all libraries (necessarily have to) agree on a specific data type (or at least a type that's binary layout-compatible), yet Rust's type system leaves a lot of headroom to encode circumstantial information:

- [`std::os::windows::raw::HANDLE`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/raw/type.HANDLE.html) is the low-level, ABI-compatible type alias. It's literally just a `*mut c_void`, Rust's way of expressing C's `void*`.
- [`std::os::windows::io::BorrowedHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/struct.BorrowedHandle.html) is a `#[repr(transparent)]` type over the aforementioned `HANDLE` type with lifetime annotations. It is valid for as long as the referenced [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) is.
  It just landed in Rust 1.63, so there's not a lot of real world evidence how this pans out.
- [`windows::Win32::Foundation::HANDLE`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.HANDLE.html) is very similar to `std::od::windows::raw::HANDLE` in that it transparently wraps a `void*`, but stores it as an `isize` instead.

While it [has been discussed](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/1622) whether [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows)'s `HANDLE` should follow the route of lifetime-annotated `BorrowedHandle`'s this has not been implemented (as of 0.39.0). At this time, the easiest solution would be to just pull out an `as_raw_handle()` and feed that into a `HANDLE`, e.g.:

```rust
unsafe fn lock(file: &mut File) -> BOOL {
    let mut overlapped = Default::default();
    LockFileEx(
        HANDLE(file.as_raw_handle() as isize),
        LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK,
        0,
        !0,
        !0,
        &mut overlapped,
    )
}
```

---

As for the specific error diagnostic, the function signature of [`LockFileEx`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Storage/FileSystem/fn.LockFileEx.html) is:

```rust
pub unsafe fn LockFileEx<'a, P0>(
    hfile: P0,
    dwflags: LOCK_FILE_FLAGS,
    dwreserved: u32,
    nnumberofbytestolocklow: u32,
    nnumberofbytestolockhigh: u32,
    lpoverlapped: *mut OVERLAPPED
) -> BOOL where
    P0: Into<HANDLE>,
```

`rustc` is attempting to invoke an `Into` (or `From`) trait implementation on the `hfile` argument, but cannot find one that matches. This is because it doesn't exist, not just because the caller failed to `use` the specific trait implementation.